# Jitsi trough Tor (browser)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am trying to use Jitsi trough Tor browser, but it is not working. There is no error notification. Jitsi simply doesn't go online.

Can you help?

Comment: You mean https://jitsi.org/? What do you exactly mean by "Jitsi simply doesn't go online"? The Firefox's indicator of activity (rotating circle on the tab) disappears and the page stays blank? --- Please take this into account if you are trying to use standalone applications (I mean not running inside Firefox): With Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) only the Firefox from the TBB communicates through Tor by default.

Comment: Same here.<br>
<br>
In Jitsi, I went to: Options -> Advanced -> Global Proxy: <br>
Proxy type: SOCKS5<br>
Proxy server: localhost<br>
Proxy port: 9150 (Since TBB, otherwise 9050)<br>
<br>
Yet, it won't connect.